# building android apk with aapt with resources in dependency jar

Tags: java, android, jar, aapt

We have our own build system for android for a multitude of reason.  We currently build the apk with aapt.  Problem is now there is a dependency to a jar file that contains custom resources.  For example the jar file looks like this:

```
/META-INF
/foo.properties
/my_custom_dir/
/i_hate_my_life/
```

using the following command :

```
aapt p --auto-add-overlay -f \
    -M src/main/AndroidManifest.xml \
    -I $(ANDROID_HOME)/platforms/android-19/android.jar \
    -S src/main/res/ \
    -S $(ANDROID_HOME)/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/ \
    -S $(ANDROID_HOME)/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/ \
    -F bin/SampleApp.unaligned 1>/dev/null
```

totally ignores those extra directories and my app crashes well because that jar needs those little buggers.

I've tried the -j switch and that only includes the classes.  Anyone have a clue other than to write a custom script or unzip the third party jar and use appt add (barf)?

Before you say use ant or gradle...it's not an option!

**UPDATE**:

For now I have this nastyness in my Makefile and it's working...

```
@mkdir -p bin/tmp/
@for i in $(JARS_MIN); do\
    cp $$i bin/tmp/; \
done;
@cd bin/tmp/; \
for i in `ls`; do\
    unzip -o $$i; \
    rm $$i; \
    rm -rf META-INF/; \
    rm -rf com/; \
    rm -rf org/; \
    rm -rf android/; \
    rm -rf edu/; \
    rm -rf javax/; \
    rm -rf net/; \
done;
cd bin/tmp/; zip -g -r ../SampleApp.unaligned *
```

Comment: You can improve your shell script slightly by avoiding the first for loop and copying all files at once `cp $(JARS_MIN) bin/tmp/`. Another improvement would be to collapse all the `rm` lines into one `rm -rf META-INF/ com/ org/ ...`. And finally, you don't need to copy (and subsequently delete) the jar files at all. Just `cd bin/tmp; for i in $(JARS_MIN); do unzip -o ../../$$i; rm -rf META-INF com ...; done` and you're done.

Comment: Hi, can you give a quick update please? I stumbled on the EXACT same problem